# Query data.frame through Bash script argument with Rscript

Tags: r

If I have an R script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env Rscript
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

t <- read.table(args[2], header = TRUE)
print(t$args[1])

q(status = 0)
```

which I use with the TSV file "example-table.tsv":

```
"a" "b"
1 3
2 2
3 1
```

...using the Bash command: `./example.R a example-table.tsv`... (after making the R script executable, of course)

Why does `t$args[1]` return `NULL`? How do I get this example to return the proper data.frame column that I specify in the script arguments?

Thanks for you help!

I realize this may or may not be a better question for programming, rather than Cross Validated...?

Comment: could you pls try `read.table(args[2], header = TRUE, sep = "\t")` or `read.delim(args[2])`

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I did not export my dataframe properly. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
print(t[[args[1]]])
```

note that `t$args[1]` is parsed as `(t$args)[1]` -> `NULL[1]` -> `NULL` because your data.frame has no 'args' column.

Comment: Excellent!
I realized I had made some mistakes in my original question, but you nailed it.

Comment: That should be stared in the question! This is R ?Extract 101